# How can I change the terminal application that Docker Desktop for macOS launches when I click the CLI button?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-desktop

I'm using Docker Desktop 2.2 and each time I click the CLI button for a running container I get the standard Terminal.App. I would rather have iTerm2 as that is my default but there is no obvious setting in Docker Desktop to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you can't, there's an open issue for this:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4273

Edit July 2021: Just updated the client and now it opens with my default terminal.

Comment: Well, that is a bummer. Let us hope for a solution in a later version.

Comment: For now I connect to my container using iTerm and docker command. 

docker exec -it <container-name> <path-to-shell>

Example:
docker exec -it my-container /bin/sh